# how to add Mute/Un-mute button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a mute/un-mute button to my website. I created a panoramic tour using a program called Panotour by Kolor. Thing is I exported it as HTML but can't seem to find the audio tags or anything. I found the file which contains the audio files, I just need a way to mute the music.

[image: Here are the audio files that are playing in the background].

Here's what I'v done so far.

```
<div>
   <img class="img-responsive" src="Images/muteon.png" id="mute" onclick="toggleSound(this);">
</div>

    <script>
         function toggleSound(img)
              {
                  if(img.src.match(/blank/))
                     {
                        console.log('black');
                        img.src = "Images/muteon.png";
                      }
                  else
                      {
                        console.log('blank');
                        img.src = "Images/muteoff.png";
                      }
              }
  </script>
```

Comment: You should add a `Start/Stop Sounds` button to the control bar. See http://www.kolor.com/wiki-en/action/view/Panotour_-_Style_-_Plugins_library_-_Control_bar#Start.2FStop_Sounds

Comment: I will check that! Thanks!